# There's something funky about some titles in revision histories here on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, revisions-list

If you look at [the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/20807/revisions) of [Is SO pricing their site predatorially if it is making a loss?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20807/is-so-pricing-their-site-predatorially-if-it-is-making-a-loss) on Chrome 34 / Windows 7, you should see the following:

[image: title being cut off]

The behavior of the title in revision 7 is probably not by-design.

Comment: Also happens in Firefox Aurora 30.0a2.

Comment: Looks like the return [of this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106171/revision-control-title-color-overlap)

Comment: Just for record-keeping: I'm reversing the direction of the dupe closure because this post has an answer and the other one doesn't.

Comment: Fixed by design team around June 5, 2014

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because the MSE style sheet specifies the default line height as:

```css
html, body {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.3em;  /* <-- note em units here */
}
```

This has exactly the same effect as:

```css
html, body {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.3;    /* <-- no units */
}
```

...except when some other inner element changes the font size while inheriting the line height.

[This note on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Prefer_unitless_numbers_for_line-height_values) describes exactly the same issue as the one we're seeing live here.  It's titled **"Prefer unitless numbers for line-height values"**.  I'll let you all draw your own conclusions.

---

Ps. A simple specific work-around for this particular issue is:

```css
h1 { line-height: 1.3 }
```

I've included this workaround in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.14.

Pps. As of SOUP v1.14.1, this fix is also applied on [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com), as the same bug appears to be present there as well.

Comment: Ps. See also [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132671/ems-for-line-height/15135142#15135142) describing the same issue.